# Refining searches step by step

Tags: search, search-engines

Say I am searching for job openings, most results would be uninteresting, for example I might get peoples CVs instead of job openings, or I might want to exclude posts from people who post a lot (recruiters)

Is there some good way to improve searches step by step?

I have seen sometimes links like "pages like this", so i was thinking of something like that, but perhaps  letting me indicate several results that I like.

Comment: This is largely dependent on the platform where you perform the search.

Comment: I am of course open to change platform